# can't find a webelement using selenium webdriver API but can locate the webelement via firepath

Tags: selenium, xpath

Thank you for taking a look at my code & would appreciate any inputs.
I am able to locate & highlight a button using firepath but same **xpath** will not work in eclipse Ide. I've tried several approaches - no luck. The only xpath generate by firepath seems to be working

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" rowspan="2">
<button class="mediumExpressButtonOver" onclick="javascript:addAsIsMBU()" title="Add »" onmouseout="javascript:this.className='mediumExpressButton'" onmouseover="javascript:this.className='mediumExpressButtonOver'" type="button"> Add »</button>
<br/>
```

None of the following **xpath** works

1.`(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1])`

2.`(//button[@class='mediumExpressButtonOver' and type='button'])[1]`

3.`(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(@title,'Add')])[1])`

The following generated by firepath would work

**`"//*[@id='smack']/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/button[1]")`**

Could you please tell me why only the last one works & others throw

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector (//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1]) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1]) because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b', time: '2016-01-29 19:04:49'
System info: host: 'D-113066896', ip: '10.156.167.17', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=35.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: d83b16a6-93bc-4bf5-b5cc-c386bdd80ea4
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1])}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.`(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1])`

--> [1] is invalid I think.

2.`(//button[@class='mediumExpressButtonOver' and type='button'])[1]`

--> should be @type. [1] is also invalid

3.`(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(@title,'Add')])[1])`

--> again [1] is invalid

Another thing that you need to investigate is, is that element with that property unique? `ID` attribute is usually unique, therefore it works. In case of other attribute, it is usually not unique, therefore you might want to do `FindElements` and pick the right one.

Answer (score 0):

All three xpaths provided by you have incorrect syntax. Extra round bracket '`)`' is there before `[1]` in each xpath. The correct syntax would be :

```
//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')][1]
//button[@class='mediumExpressButtonOver' and type='button'][1]
//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(@title,'Add')][1]
```

However, these xpaths won't find element as they are incorrect.

The correct xpath would be :

```
//button[contains(text(),'Add')]
```

Second xpath provided by you is correct except missing `@` before type.

```
//button[@class='mediumExpressButtonOver' and @type='button'][1]
```

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur @kurakura88 @Mosam Mehta The xpath is syntactically correct due to the fact that firebug is able to find, highlight and results show matching node.


`(//td[@valign='middle']/button[contains(text(),'Add')])[1])`

The above xpath expression finds a button based on index. It is the first button so I used `[1]`

The below expression has a typo while posting a question 
`(//button[@class='mediumExpressButtonOver' and type='button'])[1]` - This doesn't work too.

@Saurabh Gaur I've used the css locator as suggested- No luck

Comment: Did you try by adding `@ ` before `type` in `(//button[@class='m‌​ediumExpressButtonOve‌​r' and @type='button'])[1]`. And did you try another suggested xpath?

Comment: Yes, I've used the correct syntax prior posting the query but missed to mention `@type` in the query. I think this is a bug with selenium but I ain't sure of it

Answer (score 0):

Actually provided `xpath` seems syntactically incorrect that's why you are unable to locate add button. I would suggest you try using `cssSelector` which would be much faster as below :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.mediumExpressButtonOver[title ~= 'Add']"));
```

Or if you want to locate using `xpath` try as below :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'Add')]"));
```

Comment: @nandeshkalyankar why no luck by using cssSelector?? Is there any exception??